# ASP.NET MVC: How to close browser window instead of returning a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, browser

I have an instance where, not by my own choice, but I have a secondary popup window in the browser.
Upon form submission back to a server-side MVC method, after this method is complete I'd like it to close that browser window that called it.

Is there a way to do this other than to return a view with javascript in the "onReady" that tells it to close?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to achieve this from the server without using javascript (or returning a view that will execute this javascript).

Answer (score 5):

Put this in your view:

```
@if (ViewBag.ShouldClose) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.close();
    </script>  
}
```

Then if you set the ShouldClose property, it'll run that script and should close the window.

```
// in your controller
ViewBag.ShouldClose = true;
```

Note: I did this from the editor so you might have to tweak the view syntax to get it to parse right.

Comment: only problem is, i'm not running the latest MVC, so i can't use the @ syntax. i'll just make it work with the archaic <%%> though. ;) thx.

Comment: well crap...looks like viewbag wasn't added until MVC 3 as well. either way, i know how to handle it on the client side. i was just curious as to if i could nip it in the bud on the server side. thx though.

Comment: Sure. ViewData["ShouldClose"] on both sides should work I think.

Comment: You may have to do a (bool)ViewData["ShouldClose"] on the view side.

Comment: Of course, my personal preference is to use a model class and strongly typed view. In that case, just put a public bool ShouldClose {get; set;} and read / write it on the server / view side.

Comment: @MVelasquez - Thanks! BTW, if you thought this answered your question be sure to accept it in the question/answer options.

Comment: I find that this still leaves the _LayoutView open.
I thought I'll put the View code in _Layout but still does the same.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and the answer of @Michael Kennedy was exactly what I needed! Since I am using MVC 2 I did have to alter the syntax. I'll put it here as a reference for others.

In the view:

```
<% if ((bool)ViewData["ShouldClose"]) { %>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.close();
</script>
<% } %>
```

In the controller:

```
ViewData["ShouldClose"] = true;
```

Don't forget to set the ViewData in each call to the view otherwise you'll get a NullReference for the cast to bool.